# Renaming mounted folder gives "Permission denied"

Tags: command-line, mount, files, rename

I have 5 different drives in my PC which are located at `/home/mnt/FOLDERS` and are by default labelled alphanumerically.

Now I want to rename them and I tried using `mv`, `rename`, `sudo` commands, which however didn't work, saying `Permission denied`.

What command can I use to rename these folders?

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to create the mount points yourself in /Home/mnt/[...] and then mount them in fstab

Comment: Hard to understand your question, all the commands you mention need arguments to work with. But I think the problem is, that you cannot change the name of a folder which is currently in use as a mountpoint, even when you are root, it's just not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest unmounting `umount` all these drives one by one, then changing the directory names to your new names using the `mv` command, and then editing your `/etc/fstab` with the new mount paths, and finally reboot your computer.

To unmount run:

```
umount /home/mnt/name
```

To edit fstab:

```
sudo vim /etc/fstab
```

or

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

But please please be careful when editing your `fstab`!!

I would also recommend obtaining the UUIDs of the drives first using:

```
sudo blkid
```

so that you can edit your `fstab` properly.

There is a lot of community help on how to edit the `fstab` and permanently mount drives. I would suggest you familiarise yourself first before you touch the `fstab`.  Please be careful.